# How do I upgrade the PHP version used?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop, 9

I've been away from Drupal a few years. I now want to develop a site. I see it's up to version 9. However, when I tried to install Drupal 9 in DevDesktop to get a feel for it, I got the message *PHP version too old.* I'm selecting the highest PHP version, 7.1.12, and still get this message. I know D9 likes PHP 7.5 or something, but how do I get that?

Should I simply upgrade PHP locally, independent of DevDesktop? Or is DevDesktop now old school, replaced by something better?

Comment: "If you are Drupal developer or plan to be, you should consider using a Virtual Machine development environment or a Docker development environment which can run on Windows as well." Source: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/windows-development-environment/installing-drupal-on-windows-for

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Acquia Dev Desktop (released on May 21, 2020) is compatible with Drupal 9: It added support for MySQL 5.7 and Drush 10; PHP has been updated to versions 7.2.28 and 7.3.15.

Since Drupal 9 requires PHP 7.3 or higher, you need to select version 7.3.15 for Drupal 9, or you will get the error message you saw.

#### References

- [The release notes for Drupal 9](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/9.0.0)
- The [download page for Acquia Dev Desktop](https://dev.acquia.com/downloads)

  > [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but I'm using the latest ver of DD, and it only allows me to select php 7.1.12.  I'm on a Mac.

Comment: I tried installing DD again and it has an error, even though it installs partially, enough to function. But all the php versions don't install. Darn.